# browser.tabs undefined in Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am writing a Microsoft Edge extension.

I have the following manifest file:

```
{
  "author": "",
  "description": "Test",
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [        
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["script.js"],
    "matches": ["*://*/*"]
  }],
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-40x40.png"
  }
}
```

When i put into my script.js:

```
var currentTab = browser.tabs.getCurrent();
alert(currentTab.index);
```

It fails because browser.tabs is undefined?

Why?

[image]

Comment: are you trying to port a Chrome extension? if so, see 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions and https://www.microsoft.com/el-GR/store/p/microsoft-edge-extension-toolkit/9nblggh4txvb?rtc=1

Comment: No, just writing a fresh microsoft edge plugin.

Comment: is the browser object defined ok? if it is, then if tabs isn't, it might be a permissions issue

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis - Yea, browsers is there, tabs isn't

Comment: so is there a chance the manifest has wrong syntax, or has wrong encoding or isn't packaged correctly for Edge to find it?

Comment: I encountered the same problem.
I move script from content to background.html and browser.tabs get its value.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. In background.js is browser.tabs defined, but you can't use browser.tabs.getCurrent() in background. In content, browser.tabs is undefined. It works in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from content script as it has limitations.

browser.tabs API can only be used/available in background script and Browser action popup scripts. To achieve your intended functionality you can send a message to background script and in the background script you can utilize the browser.tabs API.

Answer (score -1):

You can call this function `browser.tabs.getCurrent()` in contexts where there is a browser tab, such as an options page. If you call it from a background script or a popup, it will return undefined.But as I see you have used this function in content script, so it shouldn't be a problem.

This is an asynchronous function that returns a Promise.

You can check [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent) for further information on how to use the function for Edge Extension.

Also you shouldn't leave the author field empty, it may give some error . So try writing you name in it.

Comment: But it is compatible with edge hence it should work and I have myself used it

Comment: I've added a piccy to my OP, i wonder what it is that i've broken :)